# Можно ли проверить наличие носителя цифровой подписи в компьютере средствами js

Tags: javascript, цифровая-подпись, криптопро

Есть рутокен, необходимое ПО от криптоПРО... Так вот по дизайну требуется выводить сообщение: "Присоедините к компьютеру носитель ключа электронной подписи.". То есть если я его вытащу из USB должно появиться это сообщение...возможно ли реализовать такую проверку на клиенте?

Comment: смотря что из себя представляет клиент

Comment: 90% что нет. доступность ключевого носителя через api плагина это потенциальная дыра в безопасности.